# Create Two Column Array From One Column Array Using Delimiter in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, latitude-longitude, delimiter

I have a JavaScript array of latitudes and longitudes. Right now, my array is in this format and is of type Array:

```
[Lat,Lon]

[Lat,Lon]

[Lat,Lon]
```

I would like to turn this one column array into a two column array with this format:

```
[Lat][Lon]

[Lat][Lon]

[Lat][Lon]
```

How can I do this in JS? My best guess involves using the comma from the one column array as a delimiter, but I'm not sure how to implement this. I am open to using JQuery.

I attempted to split my data using this code, but

```
var getOutline = 'lat1,lon1/lat2,lon2/lat3,lon3'; //Sample
var temporaryArray = new Array();
temporaryArray = getOutline.split("/");
console.log(temporaryArray)

var temporaryArray2 = new Array();
temporaryArray2 = temp.split(",");
console.log(temporaryArray2)
```

However, my second won't work because the split function doesn't split Array types.

Comment: Please show us your own attempt on creating this

Comment: var _arr = []; arr.map(function(item){_arr.push(item.split(','))})

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen edited

Comment: Definitely use jQuery for this, it can do just about anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next one if it's needed `{lat1: {lon1: value, lon2: ...}, ...}`:

```
var getOutline = 'lat1,lon1/lat2,lon2/lat3,lon3',
    result = {};

getOutline.split('/').forEach(function (coord) {
    var tmp = coord.split(',');
    result[tmp[0]][tmp[1]] = '{something that is needed as a value}';
});
```

Or, if it's needed `[[lat1, lon1], [lat2, lon2], ...]`:

```
var getOutline = 'lat1,lon1/lat2,lon2/lat3,lon3',
    result = [];

getOutline.split('/').forEach(function (coord) {
    result.push(coord.split(',').map(Number));
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Your second solution is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Guess I misunderstood the question because this is the exact format you said you didn't want: `[
    "lat1",
    "lon1"
  ],
  [
    "lat2",
    "lon2"
  ],
  [
    "lat3",
    "lon3"
  ]`

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins, I've updated reply to convert string to numbers

Comment: Its not about strings or numbers. The question stated the data is already in `[Lat,Lon]` and but it was needed in `[Lat],[Lon]` format but then the accepted answer ends up being in `[Lat,Lon]` format. It was just the OP was having a problem with the split function. This will be misleading to new readers assuming they can convert `[[Lat,Lon],[Lat,Lon]` formatted data into a two dimensional array using this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can map through the array and split each value into multiple.

```
var array = [
  '1,2',
  '3,4',
];

var newArray = array.map(function(i) {
  return i.split(',');
});

// Returns an array of arrays
// [ [1, 2], [3, 4] ]
```

Comment: Not sure that is exactly what the op wants

Comment: Yea I'm not entirely sure either, hopefully he will clarify it.